# C++ unit test on x86, target is ARM: what could go wrong?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, gcc, x86, arm

My final target is ARM 32-bit - iMX6 - but I'm **compiling** the tests for x86 (32-bit) and running them on Windows 10 x64.

What compiler options could result in getting different unit test results between my target and Windows?

Comment: Never mind the compiler options, the results of undefined behaviour could be completely different because, well, they're undefined.

Comment: I'm all for using PC test cases to hammer out the logic on an easy-to-debug platform like a PC, but you'll probably want to do more than just integration testing on the target.

Comment: @user4581301 but are there certain compiler options that are more likely to cause differences? For example: if I do NOT specify `-OptionX`, will code get generated such that the differences between x86 and ARM would result in different computations?

Comment: @user4581301 I agree; I'm not in charge of this decision and just want to know how to get ready for the bugs we won't catch.

Comment: Any of the floating point flags can make a difference in the results of floating point calculations.  Any of the optimizations flags can have a drastic affect on a program if it has UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver what’s UB?

Comment: **U**ndefined **B**ehavior.  Basically it is when you break the rules of C++ but C++ doesn't mandate that any particular thing be done when you do so, like accessing an array out of bounds, or using a `int` before you give it a value.  In those situations, "anything" can happen

Comment: @Adrian: you could cross-compile your unit-testing framework and your tests for use with QEMU in semihosting mode with the very same ARM compiler you are planning to use, and almost the same compiling/linking options. I did this once with cppunit and catched real bugs.

Comment: @Adrian:  By the way, what is your target environment ? bare-metal, RTOS (which one), or Linux ?  is the target a Cortex-A7 or a Cortex-A9? Which compiler are you using ? what is its version ? Another option would be to buy a cheap SBC with the CPU you are targeting, and to compile/execute your unit tests on it. This can be done from u-boot, if your target is bare-metal, or from Linux . This is  worth convincing the person "in charge of this decision" that testing on Windows/x86 is very risky, as pointed-out in the posts above.

Comment: If your code uses `std::atomic`, testing on x86 won't expose some mistakes in memory ordering that are only visible with runtime reordering on a weakly-ordered ISA like ARM.  (x86 asm is seq_cst + a store buffer.  ARM asm is mo_relaxed / mo_consume).

Comment: @PeterCordes in all fairness, tests are unlikely to uncover these types of bugs any real ARM target either.

Comment: @marko: you mean because they often require very rare timing coincidences?  If your unit tests hammer really hard (much more contention than the real production use-case), that can sometimes help.  Or do you mean some real ARM HW doesn't have very large reordering windows, like store-buffer size and number of outstanding loads it can track?  So a PowerPC might be a better choice?

Comment: @PeterCordes probably more the former.   You can write a test and run it millions of times, but can't prove that your system is free of rare race conditions.

Comment: @marko: right, of course not.  But it's also possible (I think) to write code that happens to work fine on x86 (because compile-time reordering doesn't happen or isn't sufficient to expose a problem) but faceplants quickly on a weakly-ordered ISA.  Testing on ARM will catch that at least, and is useful if the desired target is ARM.  Logical reasoning about the code is 100% required for lockless multithreaded code, not just throwing code at the compiler until it passes tests.  But testing is still a good idea.

Comment: This is absolutely the case.  You'd have to make sure the tests were compiled optimised - not always the case!